# Transfer IMAP email accounts?

Tags: imap

I want to transfer a website including a domain and 6 mail accounts to another hosting provider. Well, the transfer off a website isn't a challenge. But how i can transfer 6 mail accounts?

Transfer the domain to the new provider, export all mails from the mail accounts, create the new mail accounts at the new provider and import the mails?

Which way is preferred and save? Are there tools to create a backup of an IMAP mail account?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please consider your operating infrastructure. A simple SO search finds a lot of references including cPanel and Plesk. Consider also this answer:  [Question 5953227](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953227/transfer-emails-to-new-hosting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically i backup with my local mail client all my IMAP email accounts and then migrate it to the new accounts after transfer the domain successfully!